# Filter and keep NA

Tags: r

```
my_df <- tibble(
  b1 = c(2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, NA), 
  b2 = c(NA, 4, 6, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 7), 
  b3 = c(5, 9, 8, NA, 2, 3, 1, 6, NA), 
  b4 = c(NA, 6, NA, 10, 12, 14, 3, 6, 2))
```

Hello,

I have a df like this, and I want to filter b4 and (keep all rows with NA and 6) . I have tried  my_df %>% filter(b2 %in%c("6", "NA")) which unfortunately did not retain the blanks (NA) in b4. Any suggestion please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, `my_df %>% filter(is.na(b4) | b4 == 6)` this one?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution if b4 is numeric:

```
my_df %>% 
  filter(is.na(b4) | b4 == 6)
```

Just add quotes to the 6 if needed, ie if b4 isn't numerical

Comment: Nice @lofus77 :)